how to save pyspark daframe as jsonl/json file?
example contrived for this question. I have a pyspark dataframe, for ease, i have hardcoded the data, but i have bunch of csv files that i read into the dataframe. I can save the dataframe as json or at lease convert pyspark dataframe to pandas and then output it as a json file. but is it possible to output each line/row of dataframe , into json file and add a new line at the end , essentially as a jsonl file?
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = [("Alice", 25), ("Bob", 30), ("Charlie", 35)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "age"])

# Save the DataFrame as JSON
df.write.json("path/to/output.json")


I think pyspark writes it as jsonlines already? I assume U inspected the saved data in its raw state

please add an example of what you currently have and what would be the expected output

When you write your pyspark DF you can use the lineSep option.
Example
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DateType, FloatType
from datetime import datetime

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ExampleDataFrame").getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
    StructField("account", StringType(), True),
    StructField("date", DateType(), True),
    StructField("amount", FloatType(), True)
])


data = [
    ("account1", datetime(2024, 10, 1), 150.75),
    ("account1", datetime(2024, 10, 2), 200.50),
    ("account2", datetime(2024, 10, 1), 305.20),
    ("account2", datetime(2024, 10, 3), 120.80),
    ("account3", datetime(2024, 11, 1), 510.30),
    ("account3", datetime(2024, 11, 2), 75.00),
    ("account1", datetime(2024, 12, 1), 45.60),
    ("account2", datetime(2024, 12, 3), 300.45)
]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").json("path", lineSep="\n")

Output
{"account":"account1","date":"2024-10-01","amount":150.75}
{"account":"account1","date":"2024-10-02","amount":200.5}
{"account":"account2","date":"2024-10-01","amount":305.2}
{"account":"account2","date":"2024-10-03","amount":120.8}
{"account":"account3","date":"2024-11-01","amount":510.3}
{"account":"account3","date":"2024-11-02","amount":75.0}
{"account":"account1","date":"2024-12-01","amount":45.6}
{"account":"account2","date":"2024-12-03","amount":300.45}

For your information :
JSON Lines enables applications to read objects line-by-line, with each line fully describing a JSON object (https://jsonlines.org/examples/)

thanks . what does  coalesce(1) do ?

You can ignore it, it allow to reduces the DataFrame to a single partition. I used it in local to have only 1 output file :)
